# Trying to set a CSS property on one element while iterating a different one

Tags: jquery, css

I've got some boxes which I want to lay out with `position:absolute;`.

```
$('.tt-sessions-in-room').each(function(index){ 
        $(this).css('left', left);
        left = left + $(this).width() + extra_width;
});
```

Which is lovely. However I also want to match some other boxes to the same absolute position only above them.

If I try matching in the same `.each()` like so

```
$('.tt-sessions-in-room, .tt-roomname').each(function(index){
```

then it iterates through as one long list, and the `.tt-roomnames` are positioned off to the right.

How would I grab each element of `.tt-roomname` and set its left CSS? My current thinking is to build an array and do each of them at the same time as I iterate through the array - but is there a better way using `.each()` ?

Comment: try `if ($(this).hasClass('tt-roomname')) { // change right positioning } else { // change left positioning }` or invert it so you're checking for `tt-sessions-in-room` if you prefer.

Comment: Need clarification on how your DOM is structured. Which element is the parent and which one the child?

Comment: They're both child elements of a different parent. I could have structured them in an <ul>, but then the first <li> (the room) would have been different to all the others (the sessions in the room).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I can use the (index) to iterate, by checking for the other element's .eq()

```
$('.tt-sessions-in-room').each(function(index){ 
        $(this).css('left', left);
        left = left + $(this).width() + extra_width;
        $('.tt-room').eq(index).css('left', left);
});
```